# Changing span text to hide/show on jQuery toggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

strong textI'm trying to Hide/Show a div by clicking on Span element. I'm trying to change the text inside the span to toggle between hide(when element is showing) and show(when element is hidden). i belie I got on a good start but I'm now stuck in getting the jQuery script to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3AnPX/): http://jsfiddle.net/3AnPX/

HTML

```
<span class="help_target">Open</span>
<div class="help_content">Content 1</div>

<span class="help_target">Open</span>
<div class="help_content">Content 2</div>

<span class="help_target">Open</span>
<div class="help_content">Content 3</div>

<span class="help_target">Open</span>
<div class="help_content">Content 4</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".help_content").hide();

$(".help_target").click(function () {
    $(this).next('.help_content').toggle();
    $(this).toggle(function () {
        $(this).text('Open');
    }, function() {
        $(this).text('Close');
    });
});
```

**Update:**

Trying to implement this on my actual website, but it's not working:  http://jsfiddle.net/PzkxA/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the visibility of toggled element to change the text:

```
if(!$(this).next('.help_content').is(":visible") )
    $(this).text('Open');
else
    $(this).text('Close');
```

Update:

```
 $("span.hideshow").click(function () {
  $(this).closest('.profilestats-courseblock').find('.profilestats-course-badges').toggle();
  $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Close' ? 'Open' : 'Close');
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PzkxA/2/)**

Comment: Cannot get this to work when i actually implement it in my website. check here:  http://jsfiddle.net/PzkxA/

Comment: They both toggle at the same time. I doubt it's my browser: I'm using Firefox on a mac.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late but another way here `:)` **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/q76dk/

So probably all you want is to cahgne the text nsince the `.help_content` is outside `span`

Hope this fits your needs. `:)`

**code**

```
$(".help_content").hide();
$(".help_target").click(function () {
    $(this).next('.help_content').toggle();

    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Close' ? 'Open' : 'Close');

    });
```

Comment: Cannot get this to work when i actually implement it in my website. check here:  http://jsfiddle.net/PzkxA/

Comment: @iammikerodriguez bro `:)` giving me working demo :)) try clicking on this in your demo `section-header` works like a awesomeness

Comment: You're original code was flawless, but when I actually tried to implement the logic on my website, they were not toggling. Now, both toggle at the same time, whenever i click one. http://jsfiddle.net/PzkxA/

Comment: @iammikerodriguez saweet got you, see above you have a solution it must be with the fact that you are using global level `.profilestats-course-badges` if you use it in **this** context you will be fine `:)~